SchedulerBuilder vs. StdSchedulerFactory
I have been using StdSchedulerFactory to create and configure schedulers in my Quartz.NET applications. However, I recently came across SchedulerBuilder and noticed that it's also used to create schedulers, but I couldn't find much explanation in the official documentation regarding the differences between the two approaches.
Could someone clarify the key differences between using SchedulerBuilder and StdSchedulerFactory to instantiate and configure a Quartz.NET scheduler? Specifically, in which scenarios would one be more appropriate than the other?
Any insights on when to prefer one over the other, especially in terms of flexibility, configuration options, and ease of use, would be greatly appreciated.

SchedulerBuilder powers MS DI integration under the hood and offers the strongly-typed configuration experience. Generally I would recommend using the scheduler builder approach as it should be able to configure pretty much all the scenarios that you can with StdSchedulerFactory.
SchedulerBuilder internally populates the needed configuration keys for the properties that StdSchedulerFactory will be fed with.
